# Two problems, weird 'undefined' and removing strings if other string is not there

Tags: javascript, string, input

```js
function button2() {
a1 = document.getElementById('line1').value;
a2 = document.getElementById('line2').value;
a3 = document.getElementById('line3').value;
a4 = document.getElementById('line4').value;
a5 = document.getElementById('line5').value;
a6 = document.getElementById('line6').value;
a7 = document.getElementById('line7').value;
a8 = document.getElementById('line8').value;
v = document.getElementById('linksC').innerHTML;
this.code1 = document.getElementById('affiliate').value;
this.cc;

if (a1 !== ' ' && this.code1 + a1) {this.cc += a1+this.code1 + '<br>'} else {this.code1 = ' ';};
if (a2 !== ' ') {this.cc += a2+this.code1 + '<br>'};
if (a3 !== ' ') {this.cc += a3+this.code1 + '<br>'};
if (a4 !== ' ') {this.cc += a4+this.code1 + '<br>'};
if (a5 !== ' ') {this.cc += a5+this.code1 + '<br>'};
if (a6 !== ' ') {this.cc += a6+this.code1 + '<br>'};
if (a7 !== ' ') {this.cc += a7+this.code1 + '<br>'};
if (a8 !== ' ') {this.cc += a8+this.code1 + '<br>'};

document.getElementById('linksC').innerHTML = this.cc;



}
```

```html
<p>
multiple links.</p>
<p>link 1</p>
<input type="text" id="line1">
<p>link 2</p>
<input type="text" id="line2">
<p>link 3</p>
<input type="text" id="line3">
<p>link 4</p>
<input type="text" id="line4">
<p>link 5</p>
<input type="text" id="line5">
<p>link 6</p>
<input type="text" id="line6">
<p>link 7</p>
<input type="text" id="line7">
<p>link 8</p>
<input type="text" id="line8">

<p>affiliate code insert</p>
<input type="text" id='affiliate'>
<br><br>
<button onclick="button2()">combine link with code</button> <br><br>
<div id="linksC"></div>
```

Problem number one:
for some reason i'm getting a weird undefined before the input text. if i clicked on the button to combine the inputs, i'm getting this printed undefined.

problem number two:
If i'm adding the affiliate code, i don't want it to print if the links are empty.

thank you in advance for reading this.

Comment: could you post your code.

Comment: just did.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cc;` is undifened, you should assign a value to it before concatenating other values to it, e.g. `cc = '';`

Also remove the whitespaces between the single quotes in your if statements to check if they are an empty string.

edit: removed this from the variables as pointed out by @charlietfl

```js
function button2() {
a1 = document.getElementById('line1').value;
a2 = document.getElementById('line2').value;
a3 = document.getElementById('line3').value;
a4 = document.getElementById('line4').value;
a5 = document.getElementById('line5').value;
a6 = document.getElementById('line6').value;
a7 = document.getElementById('line7').value;
a8 = document.getElementById('line8').value;
v = document.getElementById('linksC').innerHTML;
code1 = document.getElementById('affiliate').value;
cc = '';

if (a1 !== '' && code1 + a1) {cc += a1+code1 + '<br>'} else {code1 = '';};
if (a2 !== '') {cc += a2+code1 + '<br>'};
if (a3 !== '') {cc += a3+code1 + '<br>'};
if (a4 !== '') {cc += a4+code1 + '<br>'};
if (a5 !== '') {cc += a5+code1 + '<br>'};
if (a6 !== '') {cc += a6+code1 + '<br>'};
if (a7 !== '') {cc += a7+code1 + '<br>'};
if (a8 !== '') {cc += a8+code1 + '<br>'};

document.getElementById('linksC').innerHTML = cc;

}
```

```html
<p>
multiple links.</p>
<p>link 1</p>
<input type="text" id="line1">
<p>link 2</p>
<input type="text" id="line2">
<p>link 3</p>
<input type="text" id="line3">
<p>link 4</p>
<input type="text" id="line4">
<p>link 5</p>
<input type="text" id="line5">
<p>link 6</p>
<input type="text" id="line6">
<p>link 7</p>
<input type="text" id="line7">
<p>link 8</p>
<input type="text" id="line8">

<p>affiliate code insert</p>
<input type="text" id='affiliate'>
<br><br>
<button onclick="button2()">combine link with code</button> <br><br>
<div id="linksC"></div>
```